# Attending a lecture, with slide projection, on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, electricity, college-university-school

On Shabbat, may I go to a public lecture and look at the screen? Slides from a computer are projected onto a projection screen. The lecturer may be using a microphone. The lecture will take place whether or not you attend.

Comment: you have a few different questions here (is learning non-jewish material inherently not part of Sabbath observance, can one capitalize of a non-Jew's use of forbidden technology on the Sabbath, is one misleading others into mistake if he attends such a lecture though he is visibly Jewish, will this lead to other violations...among others). Could it be focused or split up?

Comment: I think this is a good question if the last part, about non-Jewish topics, is spun off into its own question.  (After all, that question is interesting regardless of the technologies that are or aren't in use.)

Comment: It could also be more generalized to include any number of scenarios in which one is part of a group for whom someone is doing Melachah.

Comment: @Dan, I think that the question is sound. The scenario is a very common one (happens all the time in colleges everywhere) and the question asks, essentially, whether anything is wrong with attending a college class or convention lecture or the like on the sabbath.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28235/overhead-projector-on-shabbos

Comment: Is the lecturer Jewish, non-Jewish, or unknown? If unknown, are you in a Jewish place like Tel Aviv, or a non-Jewish place like Tokyo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Rabbi Torczyner's [lecture on attending conferences](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/765631/Rabbi_Mordechai_Torczyner/Medical_Halachah-_Attending_Medical_Conferences_on_Shabbos).

If I understood and recall his lecture correctly: Generally speaking, where necessary it would be permissible — assuming that the speaker would be using the same electronic devices regardless of your presence.

(Rabbi Torczyner always starts with "ask your local synagogue rabbi for actual psak", of course.)