# Why is semicha specifically to ordain a Rabbi to give psak?

Tags: torah-study, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, semicha

Was the original process of semicha merely intended to provide reliable decisors of halacha only?

Nowadays can a Rav get semicha in Tanach or Talmud (for example)? Since, perhaps, these days the title 'Rabbi' is more symbolic of status, why wouldn't this be the case?

Comment: There is again no such thing as semichah to give a psak. Anyone can do it without semicha as long as he knows the subject. For certain things semicha was necessary in the olden times non of which I think apply today. The reason for semicha is only because one is not allowed to give a psak where one rebbi lives and some say even further afield. The semicha gives one permission for this.

Answer (score -1):

Smiche is needed to write anything about Yore Dea (specifically Kashrus). I heard that was actually one of the reasons the Chofetz Chaim never wrote about it.
Also to be a Rov means that people can ask you about practical details, something a Maggid Shiur won't answer (I saw it quite often actually that important Roshei Yeshive never answered Haloche)

Comment: user2721, are you [enamored with that number](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28235/overhead-projector-on-shabbos#comment67506_28235)? :) Also, there are other many subjects in Yoreh De'ah that are complex; why would Kashruth be the one that requires Semichah? Do you have a source for the C"C story? I can also think of other reasons why Roshei Yeshivah might be hesitant to answer practical questions of Halachah.

Comment: An interesting idea but without any source it sounds more like an urban legend.

Comment: If i remember correctly I heart the C'C part from Rabbi Braun, the Menahel of Ohr Somayach in Monsey.

Comment: Did Rav Elyashiv ztzl never pasken on kashrus?