Does Tzovei'ah apply to Dichromatism?
Dichromatism is when a material's hue changes with its concentration and thickness.
For example, pumpkin seed oil changes color based on how much of the liquid is present. And ground-up green leaves in alcohol (ethanol or isopropyl) display a red spot when shined at with a flashlight, while the rest of the liquid appears green (based on the mixture ratio).
Would it be Rabbinically forbidden to cause a dichromatic solution to have light cast on it on Shabbos, since it's changing the colors? Is handling pumpkin seed oil considered Tzovei'ah?
Note the flashlight shining on the solution, which causes a red spot to appear amidst the green:

Pumpkin seed oil exhibiting dichromatism:


https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37975/759

R Ovadia Yosef, who required sunglasses for everyday use, ruled that Transition Lenses are fine on Shabbat. Only actual pigments are problematic. These tricks of the light aren't an issue.
There is a typo in this, in the sentence that contains whatsoever"
https://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx?HalachaID=3384
